# Get values from textbox and pass it into stored procedure using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have table that has several textbox and i would like anyone to make changes the values in the textbox, but whenever someone puts some new value then they have to hit the update button which update the values. The problem is that when i run the code, the new value is not captured at all and it always shows the old value.  when am i missing here? thanks
Here is the one textbox in a table

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="myText" runat="server" Width="95%" BackColor="#ffff99" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
 public void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            ID= Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

            string test= myText.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_Update";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myColumn", test.ToString());

        }
    }
```

and here is my update query in the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Update_Response1]
(
    @ID numeric(1,0),
    @myColumn varchar(300) 
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
UPDATE myTable SET [myColumn] = @myColumn 
WHERE [ID] = @ID
and NBR = '1' ;

SELECT  ID
      ,myColumn
      ,Name
      ,Address
  FROM MyTable
  GO
```

Comment: Check your Page_Load, probably you are clearing the text box at postback. In that case, wrap it with `If(!IsPostBack){}`.

Comment: Have you stepped through that click event and made sure the values of ID and test are as you expect?

Comment: The stored procedure names don't match...

Comment: yes, i have just stepped through and the new value was in the text box so it looks like my update query in the stored procedure not working.  i have just posted my stored procedre pls look at it thnks

Answer (score 0):

In your `Page_Load` event, put the following:

```
if(!PostBack)
{
    // Set text box value here so that it only loads initial value once
}
```

Comment: i have added in my page load event this: if  (!IsPostBack) but still not working.  i am just pulling my hair now, not sure what is happening

Comment: Karl, can you look into my stored procedure? i just posted now maybe that one is wrong.  thanks